# Why empty functions aren't removed as dead code in LLVM IR?

Tags: c, clang, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-codegen

Starting with this simple C program:

```
void nothing(void) {}
int main() {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    nothing();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My passes output as follows:
Note: IR statements are in Green.

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone ssp uwtable
define void @nothing() #0 {
entry:
  ret void
}

; Function Attrs: nounwind readnone ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}
```

[image: IR]

**Question:** Using `O3` which considered the highest level optimization, **Why** did `nothing` function hasn't been eliminated as a dead-code?

Comment: `nothing` is exported from resulting `.obj` file, so it can not be eliminated.

Comment: @PetSerAl, Sorry, I don't understand, "exported from resulting .obj file"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The compiler has to consider the possibility, that there is another translation unit that wants to call `nothing()`. Therefore it can't be removed. The most it can do is to optimize its call out, but the function itself has to stay and its symbol exported for possible external usage.

By defining `nothing` as `static`, you give it [internal linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration), meaning that the compiler can assume `nothing` to be inaccessible outside the code it sees at the moment. This allows for optimizations, like choosing a different more performant calling convention, or in your case, eliminate the function altogether.